# Whats wrong with my ´SELECT´

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going crazy over this SELECT.
What´s wrong with it?

**ERROR CODE**

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'in' at line 2

**PHP**

```
$status = 'in';
  //Prepare query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
  WHERE usr_stamp_status = $status";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes around strings.

```
SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
WHERE usr_stamp_status = '$status'
                         ^-------^-------here
```

Otherwise the DB thinks you mean a column name instead of a value.

#### Or even better use *Prepared Statements* to let the framework handle all that for you and prevent SQL injections.

Comment: For some reason i didn't think that was nessesary! But that solved it. I must be tired. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprinf("SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
    WHERE usr_stamp_status = '%s'",$status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will generate a query

```
SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
  WHERE usr_stamp_status = in
```

So your database is confused that you are comparing a string value without quotes(your case will only work if the column is int type) which is nessasary for string comparison.

**Solution 1**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
  WHERE usr_stamp_status =".$status;
```

**Solution 2**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
      WHERE usr_stamp_status = '$status' ";
```